# Inheriting Assets from a Brokerage Firm in the U.S. to one working at an American University in Japan

Tags: usa

**I am working at an American Private University in Japan and expect to inherit the assets now held by a relative at a Stock Company in the U.S.  Can I transfer these assets to another brokerage firm in the U.S. that is allowed to do business in Japan.  The stock company now holding these assets is not allowed to do business in Japan.

Comment: Is it shares in a publicly traded company? Some private companies have specific custodians. Generally, you can transfer publicly traded shares between brokers easily, private/OTC companies and some broker-specific funds may be more problematic.